# How can I make this expression involving floating-point functions a compile-time constant?

Tags: c++, arrays, variables

I have a constant integer, steps, which is calculated using the floor function of the quotient of two other constant variables. However, when I attempt to use this as the length of an array, visual studio tells me it must be a constant value and the current value cannot be used as a constant. How do I make this a "true" constant that can be used as an array length? Is the floor function the problem, and is there an alternative I could use?

```
const int simlength = 3.154*pow(10,7);
const float timestep = 100;
const int steps = floor(simlength / timestep);

struct body bodies[bcount];

struct body {
    string name;
    double mass;
    double position[2];
    double velocity[2];
    double radius;
    double trace[2][steps];
};
```

Comment: Using `constexpr` ensures the constant might be used in constant expressions.

Comment: If this is an option you could check if utilizing a math library that support compile time computations will work for you (like gcem).

Comment: @t.niese thanks for the tip, will look into this!

Comment: @RixYarbrough please note that I have no experiences with gcem yet. I was evaluating the possibility of its usage in a library I wrote for which I want to introduce more `constexpr` features. But I haven’t yet checked it’s performance and correctness.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is not possible with the standard library's `std::pow` and `std::floor` function, because they are not `constexpr`-qualified.

You can probably replace `std::pow` with a hand-written implementation `my_pow` that is marked `constexpr`. Since you are just trying to take the power of integers, that shouldn't be too hard. If you are only using powers of 10, floating point literals may be written in the scientific notation as well, e.g. `1e7`, which makes the `pow` call unnecessary.

The `floor` call is not needed since `float`/`double` to `int` conversion already does flooring implicitly. Or more correctly it *truncates*, which for positive non-negative values is equivalent to flooring.

Then you should also replace the `const` with `constexpr` in the variable declarations to make sure that the variables are usable in constant expressions:

```
constexpr int simlength = 3.154*my_pow(10,7); // or `3.154e7`
constexpr float timestep = 100;
constexpr int steps = simlength / timestep;
```

Theoretically only `float` requires this change, since there is a special exception for `const` integral types, but it seems more consistent this way.

Also, I have a feeling that there is something wrong with the types of your variables. A *length* and *steps* should not be determined by floating-point operations and types, but by integer types and operations alone. Floating-point operations are not exact and introduce errors relative to the mathematical precise calculations on the real numbers. It is easy to get unexpected off-by-one or worse errors this way.

Comment: Thank you very much, this explains a lot! And good tips for simplicity too.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot define an array of a class type before defining the class.

Solution: Define `body` before defining `bodies`.

---

Furthermore, you cannot use undefined names.

Solution: Define `bcount` before using it as the size of the array.

---

> Is the floor function the problem, and is there an alternative I could use?

`std::floor` is one problem. There's an easy solution: Don't use it. Converting a floating point number to integer performs similar operation implicitly (the behaviour is different in case of negative numbers).

`std::pow` is another problem. It cannot be replaced as trivially in general, but in this case we can use a floating point literal in scientific notation instead.

Lastly, non-constexpr floating point variable isn't compile time constant. Solution: Use `constexpr`.

Here is a working solution:

```
constexpr int simlength = 3.154e7;
constexpr float timestep = 100;
constexpr int steps = simlength / timestep;
```

---

P.S. `trace` is a **very** large array. I would recommend against using so large member variables, because it's easy for the user of the class to not notice such detail, and they are likely to create instances of the class in automatic storage. This is a problem because so large objects in automatic storage are prone to cause stack overflow errors. Using `std::vector` instead of an array is an easy solution. If you do use `std::vector`, then as a side effect the requirement of compile time constant size disappear and you will no longer have trouble using `std::pow` etc.

Comment: Excellent, thank you. Will check out these tips. The array essentially stores all past values of the position of a body over the simulation for the sake more versatile rendering, when writing an image based off the sim. I was able to do a way bigger, way less efficient array in Python which I originally wrote this script in, and didn't get any issues with memory. I'll see if any issues come up, and optimize then.

Comment: std::floor and "cast to int" have different behaviors with negative values.  (-1.9) becomes -2 with floor, and -1 with a conversion to int.  Also, different behaviors with NaN values.  floor returns NaN, converstion to int becomes.... (???)  Gcc shows 0, but that is a detail.  The Standard says "The behavior is undefined if the truncated value cannot be represented in the destination type, and I think NaN qualifies.

Comment: @ChrisUzdavinis The UB (including NaN) case is irrelevant when comparing flooring before conversion to int with converting without flooring since UB is there in both cases. The negative case is important to understand in general, but doesn't apply to this case since the number isn't negative.

Comment: @RixYarbrough In Python there is no concept of automatic storage. Everything is essentailly dynamically allocated. That's less efficient, but you rarely have to worry about stack overflow unless you have deep recursions.

Answer (score 0):

Because `simlength` is `3.154*10-to-the-7th`, and because `timestep` is 10-squared, then the `steps` variable's value can be written as:

```
3.154e7 / 1e2 == 3.154e5
```

And, adding a type-cast, you should be able to write the array as:

```
double trace[2][(int)(3.154e5)];
```

Note that this is HIGHLY IRREGULAR, and should have extensive comments describing why you did this.

Try switching to `constexpr`:

```
constexpr int   simlength = 3.154e7;
constexpr float timestep  = 1e2;
constexpr int   steps     = simlength / timestep;

struct body {
    string name;
    double mass;
    double position[2];
    double velocity[2];
    double radius;
    double trace[2][steps];
};
```

Comment: I know, but my goal is versatility. I change these variables in the code and it's nice to set a timestep and overall simulation length to whatever is needed, without having to do the math out and plug in messy numbers.